# TypeScript does not recognize that React is being imported and used in my linter in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm building an app using React Native with TypeScript. I do my navigation using React Navigation.

In my navigator I'm using Icons from React Native Elements for the tabs. In order to use them I have to import React. But my linter does not recognize that I use it. It says:

```
[ts] 'React' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Here is my code:

```
import DetailScreen from "../screens/Detail";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/Home";
import LoadingScreen from "../screens/Loading";
import OptionsScreen from "../screens/Options";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/Settings";
import React from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  NavigationSceneRendererProps,
  NavigationTransitionProps,
  StackViewTransitionConfigs,
  TabScene,
  TransitionConfig
} from "react-navigation";

// Some other code

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  { DetailScreen, HomeScreen, OptionsScreen },
  // TODO: Rename the config from 'CustomTransitionConfig' to 'dynamicModalTransition'.
  { initialRouteName: "HomeScreen", transitionConfig: dynamicModalTransition }
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "Home",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }: TabScene) => <Icon name="ios-home" type="ionicon" color={tintColor} />
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({ SettingsScreen });

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "Settings",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }: TabScene) => <Icon name="ios-cog" type="ionicon" color={tintColor} />
};

const MainNavigator = Platform.select({
  ios: createBottomTabNavigator({ HomeStack, SettingsStack }),
  android: createDrawerNavigator({ HomeStack, SettingsStack })
});

const RootSwitch = createSwitchNavigator(
  { LoadingScreen, MainNavigator },
  { initialRouteName: "MainNavigator" }
);

export default RootSwitch;
```

What is going on here? Why does TypeScript not recognize React?

A suberror of this is that the `<Icon />`s properties each have the error:

```
[ts] '>' expected.
[ts] Cannot find name 'name'.
any
```

It just says color and type respectively.

Comment: Try doing `import * as React from "react";`.

Comment: @zeh Thank you for your help! I did, and it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the file extension `.tsx` instead of `.ts` when the file contains JSX syntax like `<Icon ... />`.